# dragging of HTML elements

Tags: javascript, html

I am performing dragging of HTML elements.All is working fine but when is mouse is hovered very fast it leaves the HTML element back and moves along. Is there any way to avoid it. Thanks in Advance....

Comment: Please show us your code, there are millions of ways to do drag'n'drop with javascript...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you use the mousemove-event of the dragged element or of the document element?
when you used the event of the dragged element, then it will not fire when you leave this element, so when the mouse moves very fast, you could get outsite the element. Hope this helps.